# googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id aborted

Tags: youtube

I have embedded youtube video on my webpage. Every time I visit the page, I am seeing error message "https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id aborted" in browser console.

Code :

```
<div class="channel-view-featured">
    <h2>Featured Video</h2>
    <a href="#" onclick="jQuery(this).next().show(); return false;" class="video-image">
        <div class="play"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></div>
        <img src="//img.youtube.com/vi/[youtube video id]/0.jpg" />
    </a>
    <div class="video-embed" style="display: none;">
        <div class="video-overlay"></div>
        <div class="video-wrap">
            <div class="close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div>
            <h2>[video name]</h2>
            <iframe id="youtube-[youtube video id]" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/[youtube video id]?enablejsapi=1&html5=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
        <h3 class="video-name">[video name]</h3>
        <ul class="video-details">
            <li>Mar 04, 2016</li>
            <li>1 minute 21 seconds</li>
            <li>2060 views</li>
        </ul>
                    <p class="video-description">[video description]</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does any one has any idea, what can be the probable issue here and how this can be solved?

Comment: Anything on this ?

Comment: This may help https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ima-sdk/CSxgIrdW1rk

Answer (score 16):

Seems Like an AdBlocker extension in enabled. you can see the same types of errors on the YouTube page itself. These Extensions block certain Web-requests if they match some sort of ad related URI.